# How to play sound without user gesture in a React web app?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

We have build a card game on top of React framework and would like to add sounds to it. There is no problem to play `new Audio()`, when clicking something. But when a sound has to be played without user gesture, like incoming chat message or its players turn, we got this error `play() can only be initiated by a user gesture`. Are there any libs, workarounds to still make sounds playing on non gesture events? I googled a lot and found little.

Answer (score 2):

This is browser based issue. Chrome doesn't allow sound to play without DOM interaction according to its autoplay audio policy. User has to interact with DOM after first loading of the application in someway to play sounds. Or you can tell browser to play sound for your application in chrome://settings/content/sound.